# Scala - Template based run time code generation

Tags: scala, code-generation, erp

I am looking for a good template based run-time code generation library in **Scala**. I need this for my ERP system to generate artifacts (html, and other code files)

Can any please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at [Scalate](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/user-guide.html). It has multiple syntax choices and if you use [SSP](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/ssp-reference.html) you can easily create templates for text other than HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is web-based, [Play](http://www.playframework.com/) has a templating system for generating the output pages.

Comment: My app is web based. But using "run time code generation library" I should be able create my own custom templates and generate artifacts like HTML5 pages, AngularJs controllers, Scala code files,etc. Does Play do that. It looks like Scalate can satisify for my requirements.

Comment: If you mean generating the template itself at runtime or creating template-based source code to be compiled on the fly, then the answer is no. Play templates are defined and type-checked at compile time and compiled to scala classes which at runtime only does the binding and final rendering.

Comment: the requirement is creating template-based source code to be compiled on the fly. Thank you for answering anyway